# My bootstrap doesn't work on OS MAC

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, macos, bootstrap-4

it's weird problem, my bootstrap doesn't work on mac OS, but it is normal on linux ubuntu ( on my another laptop ).

here i will attach an image ( The hierarchy file ).

[image: hierarchy Project]

And here the way I import bootstrap on my code (by the way i import it on my komentar_tampil.php )
[image]

Thank you for attention and any help !

Comment: You must use only one of them. preferably the .min version

Comment: It still doesn't work bro @IvánSánchez

Comment: Can you share more information about the issue?

Comment: Ok, for additional information, i create a table using bootstrap, and everything Work and Normal if i run it on my web (linux/windows OS), but everything just broken in my Mac OS #definition of work and normal is my desaign show properly @IvánSánchez

Comment: All i suspect is my bootstrap file failed to load on my Mac OS @IvánSánchez

Comment: Have you tried checking for errors in your browser developer tools?

Comment: no errrors when I inspect it, just nothing CSS script on it. @Klooven

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue.

what worked for me just now is

in the style section

add :       `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

and it works fine.

the 2 links were greyed out and that's why it wasn't styling for me, so i just added that and it works on preview.